# How to open the default software interface to search a file, like nautilus of ubuntu with python?

Tags: python-3.x, file

Im trying to write a python script to open the default software interface to search a file in linux, windows and mac, and I want to get the absolute path of the file with python.

How can I do this?

**Example**:

```
path = open(default search)
```

Comment: Be more precise what you mean with "default software interface". You only mention nautilus for ubuntu. But what do you expect for windows, mac? What about other linux distros? Also what do you mean with "default search" just a file name, a regular expression, an expression with * and ?

Answer (score 1):

To open the default application for a file or directory you should use `subprocess.run`

For Linux:

```py
subprocess.run(["xdg-open", "file_or_directory_name"], check=True)
```

For Windows:

```py
subprocess.run(["start ", "file_or_directory_name"], check=True)
```

For MacOS:

```py
subprocess.run(["open", "file_or_directory_name"], check=True)
```

Full portable example:

```py
import sys
import subprocess

open_binary = ""

if sys.platform == "linux":
    open_binary = "xdg-open"

elif sys.platform == "win32":
    open_binary = "start "

elif sys.platform = "darwin":  # MacOS
    open_binary = "open"

else:
    sys.exit(1)


subprocess.run([open_binary, "/file/or/directory/name"], check=True)
```

Comment: How I store the value of the file that the user choose in the interface in a variabel?, like I open the interface, I choose a file and click open and store the path of this file in a variable

Comment: @henriquevital I don’t know, sorry